# How to assert a url in cypress

Tags: url, automation, cypress, assertion

Hi i want to assert a url which increases on every save. Say a new job is created the url changes from job/1 to job/2. There is a increment on every newly created job.

Comment: Please add the code you tried.

Answer (score 3):

You can assert the whole URL with

```
cy.url().should('eq', 'http://localhost:8000/users/1/edit') // => true
```

Or just a part of it with

```
cy.url().should('include', '/users/1/edit') // => true
```

In your case, you could use:

```
cy.url().should('include', 'job/')
```

Answer (score 2):

or you can also assert specific URL search params like this:

```
cy.location().should(loc => {
   expect(loc.pathname).to.equal('/job/1')
})
```

read original [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/location#Syntax)

Comment: thats the issue. the url changes on every addition of new job.
 say it was job/1
when a new job is added it will change to 
job/2

Comment: ok, then I need more details or some list of step what you are trying to do and when you are trying to assert URL, can you pls add more details when this `job1 and 2` appears, please

Comment: actually every time a test case is run a new job is created. The test case is basically run for every regression. So every time the url changes. 
For example 
if i run the test case today 
the url can be this 
localhost.com/jobs/121/info 
and if i run at some later time the url can be  
localhost.com/jobs/131/info
because the 10 jobs were created btw them. this is just for better understanding.

Comment: ok, clear now, so next question do you have access to the numbers which is going to appear in the next run `/jobs/????/info`? I am thinking if you can't hardcode in assertion number of the job maybe we can get it from somewhere of your system? Let me know if you can share such kind of info, because I see only one solution to use exact number. Also FYI Plan B could be assert only `job` without number but think it is not your case right?

Comment: the job is already available so it would not be a good idea and the number is incremental. It can be any next available number :(

Answer (score 0):

Verify URL like

```
cy.url().should('eq', 'http://localhost:8000/users/1/edit')
```

You can check official cypress documentation [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/url#Href-Shorthand)